# How to use the path from resource folder with windows media player

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to use 'Properties.Resources.File' as my path for Windows Media Player. But it clearly only accepts a string. How do I get 'Namespace.Properties.Resources.File' as a usable path?

```
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Namespace.Properties.Resources.File;
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: `Resources` is only a folder until you compile your app, then they become *embedded resources*...embedded in your app.  The folder is just a organizational convenience for you and Visual Studio. Assuming Winforms given the related tag

Answer (score 0):

- First, create your own file directory. ./resources-files.
- Use as below.

```
 
  ​var​ ​soundPlayer​ ​=​ ​new​ ​System​.​Media​.​SoundPlayer​();
 pathName​ ​=​ ​@"​/resource_files/OK.wav​"​; 
 ​fileName​ ​=​ ​System​.​Web​.​HttpContext​.​Current​.​Server​.​MapPath​(​pathName​); 
 ​​soundPlayer​.​SoundLocation​ ​=​ ​fileName​; 
 ​soundPlayer​.​Play​();
```

I hope it helps my dear friend...